# Merge and Rebase why merge is working for modify files?

Tags: git

I change some files in my branch.
I press on fetch

Why It is possible to do merge and when I tried to do rebase I got error message " You have unstage files"

Could you please advise me  ?

Comment: If both a local file and its repository site counterpart are modified, then obviously the changes have to be merged. They both do contain changes. You then have to stage or commit those changes before you can go on. Otherwise you would loose those merged modifications.

Comment: I did the change in my local branch master. Why it is possible for the merge and not for rebase?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that question. Why is _what_ possible?

Comment: I created local branch master based on origin. I changed file a.js add some coment. I press on fetch and now the origin/master is update. I want to update my branch so I tried rebase and then I got error and when I tried merge it worked. why there is a different ?

Comment: Why do you want to rebase? Where to? The local branch already _is_ branched from origin/master if I got you correct. Could it be you wanted to _pull_ instead? but I see your point... Let me think...

Comment: I want that my branch will be updated so I want to do fetch rebase but before I changed some file. I know I can remove the file and do rebase but I want to understand why the command rebase origin/master is not working and merge origin/master is working

Comment: do you want to have short chat ?

Comment: You should not remove, but stash your changes prior to the pull. But that only shifts the issue _if_ conflicts arise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84914/discussion-between-arkascha-and-user1365697).